# How do I execute a shell file?

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, execute, whatsapp

I'm trying to download Whatsapp on my laptop. I am using Ubuntu desktop software. I've installed Android Emulator from http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r16-linux.tgz
I unzipped the file, opened the folder, Android-sdk-linux, opened Tools and now I'm supposed to execute the file Android, and I'm not sure how to do that. Can anyone give me any help?

Ok, so this is what I thought I was supposed to do: 
shell@shell:~$ cd Desktop
shell@shell:~/Desktop$ ./android.sh
bash: ./android.sh: No such file or directory

but then that happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the file executable first with

```
chmod +x filename.sh
```

Then start the script with

```
./filename.sh
```

or

```
/full/path/to/filename.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sh filename.sh
```

OR

```
bash filename.sh
```

Comment: Oh, yes sorry. I did try that already and it said sh: 0: Can't open android.sh

Comment: Retry with putting `sudo` in front

Comment: shell@shell:~$ sudo sh android.sh
[sudo] password for shell: 
sh: 0: Can't open android.sh
shell@shell:~$ sudo sh android.sh
sh: 0: Can't open android.sh

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to install the WhatsApp on Ubuntu:

```
wget https://www.thefanclub.co.za/sites/all/modules/pubdlcnt/pubdlcnt.php?file=https://www.thefanclub.co.za/sites/default/files/public/downloads/whatsapp-webapp_1.0_all.deb&nid=200 && sudo dpkg -i whatsapp-webapp_1.0_all.deb
```

Then enter the password and open WhatsApp using the application key.

Answer (score 0):

by default permission for any shell script is "-rw-rw-r--" first we need to change the permissions using the "chmod command" then we can run the shell script in the same way in which we run the C executable code.

To debug the shell script we need to run the shell script with the "bash -x" option as follow : $ bash -x ./